# See what happens behind a function/formula in excel?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to see what happens behind a function/formula in excel to verify that the formula does what I want (replace correct)?

For example, I have installed an Excel plugin that converts text to url friendly links.

If formulas --> show formulas is on I see in the formula field

```
=FriendlyUrl(A1)
```

And if formulas --> show formulas is off I see e.g

```
aaa-bbb-ccc
```

But I want to see what `=FriendlyUrl` really does with the text contained in cell A1. The rules it use.

Comment: `Formulas -> Formula Auditing -> Evaluate Formula` you may also want to explore the rest of the formula auditing tools

Comment: I get the same result there, =FriendlyUrl(A1) and aaa-bbb-ccc. I want to see what =FriendlyUrl() really does.

Comment: Is `FriendlyUrl` a user defined function?  Scratch that - it's from an add-in.  Is the add-in written in VBA and not protected?  You could add a breakpoint to the code and follow it through by pressing `F8`.  If it's VSTO I've no idea.